# I want to display the current time in different countries on selecting country name from a drop down list in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown list which contain name of the countries and a lable showing the current date and time. I just want to show the current Date and time of the selected country from dropdown onto that lable. I am working on ASP.Net website.

Comment: WHat have you done already?

Comment: "*the* current Date and time"? Some countries span *multiple* time zones. There isn't a single, specific, current date and time in such countries. Examples include the USA (you may have heard of them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass timezone as a dropdown list value and then use that value to fetch time of that particular country

Here is code for that :-

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcountry" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem>Select country</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="South Africa" Value="South Africa Standard Time"> </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Abu Dhabi,Mascut" Value="Arabian Standard Time"> </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta" Value="SE Asia Standard Time"> </asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

and in aspx.cs page

```
protected void ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string country = ddlcountry.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string country_name = ddlcountry.SelectedItem.ToString();

        var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(country);
        DateTimeOffset localServerTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        DateTimeOffset istambulTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(localServerTime, info);

        string datetime = istambulTime.ToString();
        Response.Write(country_name + " Time :- " + datetime);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . But in this case we have to know the value of each country like "Arabian Standard Time", "SE Asia Standard Time". and i have to hard code these values in my code . Is there is any other way to do this?? and from where i can get the  values according to country.

Comment: As @Damien_The_Unbeliever already mention in his comment that Some countries span multiple time zones. There isn't a single, specific, current date and time in such countries. I think u should add the Time Standard zone correspond to each country u can also add this info. to db and then bind your dropdownlist